# How to use barcode4j

Tags: barcode, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am using apache fop to generate the pdf .I am trying to integrate barcode into my pdf using barcode4j but it is not working.I have made following changes to the fop.bat

```
set LOCALCLASSPATH=%LOCAL_FOP_HOME%build\fop.jar
set LOCALCLASSPATH=%LOCALCLASSPATH%;'D:\xmlfo\src\ac\barcode4j-2.0\build\barcode4j-fop-ext.jar'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just adding barcode4j-fop-ext.jar is not enough because it only contains the FOP plug-in but not Barcode4J itself. Please read http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/2.0/fop-ext.html which tells you everything to get Barcode4J running with Apache FOP. HTH